# How to pass raw data in API request using Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am trying to call `login API` using Retrofit2.

But in **onResponse** i alwasy get `null` as response.

**Login API endpoint**

```
@FormUrlEncoded 
@POST("/api/login/{mobile}") 
Call<ResObj> userLogin( @Field("phoneNumber") String mobile );
```

And the **API implementation**

```
private void doLogin(final String mobile){
        Call<ResObj> call = userService.login(mobile);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResObj>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResObj> call, Response<ResObj> response) {

                    ResObj resObj = response.body(); // here i am getting null response.body()

                    if(resObj.getMessage().equals("true")){

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, ListActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("mobile", mobile);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else{
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Phone Number is incorrect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResObj> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

**ResObj class:**

```
public class ResObj {
    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

I just want to  know what causes the error and what are possible solutions.

**UPDATE**

**POSTMAN**
[image]

Comment: @KnowNoTrend is NullPointerException the same as Null Object Reference?

Comment: `ResObj resObj = response.body(); if(resObj.getMessage().equals("true")){` I think so. Also, try debugging it: instead of that, try doing `System.out.println(response.body() == null)`. It will check if it is null, which I think it is.

Comment: The name of the exception you got was `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting `null` response in your login `API`. It may be due to many reasons. You can check your `API` is working as expected or not using [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/).

And inside your code, you can prevent this type of `exception` by checking `OBJECT` is `null` or not. like the following.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<ResObj> call, Response<ResObj> response) {

       ResObj resObj = response.body();

       if(resObj != null){ // checking object is not null

          if(resObj.getStatus()){

              Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, ListActivity.class);
              intent.putExtra("mobile", mobile);
              startActivity(intent);

          } else{
              Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Phone Number is incorrect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
       }else{
          // handle null response here.
       }
}
```

**Update:**

According to your `Response JSON`, Your Model(ResObj) class should be like the following.

```
public class ResObj 
{
    private String date;

    private String address;

    private String accountName;

    private String contactPerson;

    private String timeOut;

    private String problem;

    private String srNo;

    private String fieldEngineer;

    private String joNo;

    private String irNo;

    private String designation;

    private String email;

    private String timeIn;

    private String productType;

    private boolean status;

    private String contactNo;

    public String getDate ()
    {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate (String date)
    {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getAddress ()
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress (String address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAccountName ()
    {
        return accountName;
    }

    public void setAccountName (String accountName)
    {
        this.accountName = accountName;
    }

    public String getContactPerson ()
    {
        return contactPerson;
    }

    public void setContactPerson (String contactPerson)
    {
        this.contactPerson = contactPerson;
    }

    public String getTimeOut ()
    {
        return timeOut;
    }

    public void setTimeOut (String timeOut)
    {
        this.timeOut = timeOut;
    }

    public String getProblem ()
    {
        return problem;
    }

    public void setProblem (String problem)
    {
        this.problem = problem;
    }

    public String getSrNo ()
    {
        return srNo;
    }

    public void setSrNo (String srNo)
    {
        this.srNo = srNo;
    }

    public String getFieldEngineer ()
    {
        return fieldEngineer;
    }

    public void setFieldEngineer (String fieldEngineer)
    {
        this.fieldEngineer = fieldEngineer;
    }

    public String getJoNo ()
    {
        return joNo;
    }

    public void setJoNo (String joNo)
    {
        this.joNo = joNo;
    }

    public String getIrNo ()
    {
        return irNo;
    }

    public void setIrNo (String irNo)
    {
        this.irNo = irNo;
    }

    public String getDesignation ()
    {
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation (String designation)
    {
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    public String getEmail ()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail (String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getTimeIn ()
    {
        return timeIn;
    }

    public void setTimeIn (String timeIn)
    {
        this.timeIn = timeIn;
    }

    public String getProductType ()
    {
        return productType;
    }

    public void setProductType (String productType)
    {
        this.productType = productType;
    }

    public boolean getStatus ()
    {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus (boolean status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getContactNo ()
    {
        return contactNo;
    }

    public void setContactNo (String contactNo)
    {
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }
}
```

You are passing parameter as `raw` data(according to your screen-shot). So your `API` endpoint would be like below.

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("/api/login") 
Call<ResObj> userLogin(@Body JsonObject jsonObject);
```

And call your `API` like this

```
private void doLogin(final String mobile){
      try {
           JsonObject paramObject = new JsonObject();
           paramObject.addProperty("mobile", mobile);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      Call<ResObj> call = userService.login(paramObject);
      call.enqueue(new Callback<ResObj>() {

        //your rest of code

      });
}
```

**UPDATE-2:**

To send `object` from one `Activity` to another using `intent` you have to make your model class `Percelable`. like this

```
// implements Parcelable

public class ResObj implements Parcelable { 
    // ...........your previous code here

    // just simply add the following methods

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(date);
        dest.writeString(address);
        dest.writeString(accountName);
        dest.writeString(contactPerson);
        dest.writeString(timeOut);
        dest.writeString(problem);
        dest.writeString(srNo);
        dest.writeString(fieldEngineer);
        dest.writeString(joNo);
        dest.writeString(irNo);
        dest.writeString(designation);
        dest.writeString(email);
        dest.writeString(timeIn);
        dest.writeString(productType);
        dest.writeByte((byte) (status ? 1 : 0));
        dest.writeString(contactNo);
    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ResObj> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<ResObj>() {
        public ResObj createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ResObj(in);
        }

        public ResObj[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ResObj[size];
        }
    };

    protected ResObj(Parcel in) {
        date = in.readString();
        address = in.readString();
        accountName = in.readString();
        contactPerson = in.readString();
        timeOut = in.readString();
        problem = in.readString();
        srNo = in.readString();
        fieldEngineer = in.readString();
        joNo = in.readString();
        irNo = in.readString();
        designation = in.readString();
        email = in.readString();
        timeIn = in.readString();
        productType = in.readString();
        status = in.readByte() != 0;
        contactNo = in.readString();

    }
}
```

Now pass your object via intent like the following.

```
if(resObj != null){

    if(resObj.getStatus()){

        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, ListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("your_key", resObj); // pass resObj and use same key to get data
        startActivity(intent);

    } else{
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Phone Number is incorrect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Get data from your `ListActivity` like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

     final ResObj yourObject = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("your_key"); // make sure you use same key like data.

     // Now you can use your data like that
     yourEditText.setText(yourObject.getEmail()); 
}
```

Comment: The getMessage should return true if I inputted the correct credentials and false if not. But it is getting null everytime. How do I fix it?

Comment: `{
    "status": true,
    "srNo": 1,
    "date": "11/14/2019 12:00:00 AM",
    "fieldEngineer": "Angel",
    "accountName": "Forever 21 Megamall",
    "irNo": 1,
    "joNo": 1,
    "address": "Mandaluyong City",
    "contactPerson": "Jansen Babon",
    "designation": "",
    "contactNo": "",
    "email": "",
    "timeIn": "00:00:00",
    "timeOut": "00:00:00",
    "productType": "Security",
    "problem": ""
}`

Comment: API is working fine in postman. Here is the response

Comment: ResObj is already posted. By API endpoint do you mean the base url?

Comment: I have update my ResObj but it still gets the same error.

Comment: `    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api/login/{mobile}")
    Call<ResObj> userLogin(
            @Field("phoneNumber") String mobile
    ); `

Comment: Still gets the same error :(

Comment: I did. But still gets the same error :(

Comment: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to JsonObject

Comment: yes. but i get the error of : error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to JsonObject

Comment: Do you mean this?
```
   try {
           JsonObject paramObject = new JsonObject();
           paramObject.addProperty("mobile", mobile);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Yes. I've already done that

Comment: @FormUrlEncoded
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("/api/login")
    Call<ResObj> userLogin(@Body JsonObject jsonObject);

Comment: `Call<ResObj> call = userService.login(paramObject);`  here i am not using toString().

Comment: error: exception JSONException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Comment: @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding.

Comment: It somehow worked when I input the right credentials but I get the same error when I intentionally input a wrong credential. It still says it is null.

Comment: it just says that the boolean is false.

Comment: then you have to change `JSON payload` by asking your backend developer. when invalid credentials found

Comment: What should be the appropriate response?

Comment: that is the response. the response is: {
    "status": false,
    "message": "Mobile No. does not exist."
}

Comment: Nevermind. It is working perfectly now. Thanks!

Comment: May I know what will I do if I try to fetch multiple data from API? Because here, only mobile is being fetched.

Comment: I want to display this in the android app:  ` { "status": true, "srNo": 1, "date": "11/14/2019 12:00:00 AM", "fieldEngineer": "Angel", "accountName": "Forever 21 Megamall", "irNo": 1, "joNo": 1, "address": "Mandaluyong City", "contactPerson": "Jansen Babon", "designation": "", "contactNo": "", "email": "", "timeIn": "00:00:00", "timeOut": "00:00:00", "productType": "Security", "problem": "" } `